# Can I get Jenkins to build a git tag from a passed in parameter?

Tags: git, tags, jenkins

Jenkins supports parametrized builds.

I have a deployment build that requires the tag to deploy to be specified via a parameter. (to deploy a particular tag to production)

Is there an easy way to do this with the git plugin?

I tried adding a parameter TAG_NAME, and then setting branch_specifier in the git plugin section of the job to $TAG_NAME. 
Dosen't work. I get:

```
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make the build parameterized and in the git URL box, put the name of the variable you've defined. For example: `${GIT_URL}`. This should do it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would the ${GIT_URL} variable look like if the tag is specified as a parameter? 

I'm new to Jenkins + Git, sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 10):

Will up oooold topic, since this one is in google's top.
Spent some time on this question...
Short answer:
Extensible choice plugin + groovy script. This allows to make dropdown menu already filled with existing tags.

```
def gettags = "git ls-remote -t git@github.com:mycompany/com.someproject.git".execute()
def tags = []
def t1 = []
gettags.text.eachLine {tags.add(it)}
for(i in tags)
    t1.add(i.split()[1].replaceAll('\\^\\{\\}', '').replaceAll('refs/tags/', ''))
t1 = t1.unique()
return t1
```

Long answer [here](http://lifetrace.ngc.net.ua/link/2013/08/07/jenkins-git-parametrized-build.html)

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Just like with the Git Parameter Plugin, I don't think that this plugin takes SSH credentials into account.
In any case I don't get any items in the dropdown list.

Comment: The line that starts with `def gettags` doesn't work for me because git doesn't know about SSH and I cannot add a `.ssh/config` file to the jenkins user. See my own answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543482/jenkins-git-parameter-plugin-cannot-fetch-tags

Answer (score 10):

There's [Git Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin), which allows you to do exactly that:

> This plugin allows you to assign git tag or revision number as
>   parameter in Parametrized builds. There is no need to set up anything
>   special, this plugin will read your default configuration from Git
>   Plugin.

Comment: i'm trying to use Git Parameter plugin, but for v 0.3.2 not work for release (sha1 of repo)

Comment: I am using version 0.4.0 of the Git Parameter plugin, but it doesn't seem to use the SSH credentials for the git server, so it errors out when it tries to fetch all the git tags. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543482/jenkins-git-parameter-plugin-cannot-fetch-tags

Comment: I couldn't get it to work at all so I used the Extensible Choice plugin and a PHP script, see my own answer at the linked question.