# Jenkins trigger build via specific tag

Tags: git, jenkins, tags

Can someone tell me how to setup jenkins to build from a git repo based on a specific tag?  I've done some searching and tried to setup a job to build off a specific tag, see: [Jenkins Git Plugin: How to build specific tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195900/jenkins-git-plugin-how-to-build-specific-tag) 
but I'm only able to pull the latest commit from the master branch.

This is for jenkins 2.54.  I have setup the following under SCM.

```
Repo URL and Credentials
name:  ref
Refspec: +refs/tags*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
Branch Specifier refs/tags/jenkins-test*
```

And under build trigger I have allow all branches to trigger this job.
I have a commit tagged with jenkins-test1.0 and when I test the webhook from gitlab, it succesfully kicks off the jenkins job, but its pulling the latest commit from the master branch, and not the tagged commit.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) to do this.

From one of the test cases:

Scenario: A build should be triggered when tag is created, not when it is removed.

```
Given the following generic variables are configured:
  | variable        | expression               | expressionType  | defaultValue | regexpFilter  |
  | object_kind     | $.object_kind            | JSONPath        |              |               |
  | before          | $.before                 | JSONPath        |              |               |
  | after           | $.after                  | JSONPath        |              |               |
  | ref             | $.ref                    | JSONPath        |              |               |
  | git_ssh_url     | $.repository.git_ssh_url | JSONPath        |              |               |

Given filter is configured with text: $object_kind $before $after
Given filter is configured with expression: ^tag_push\s0{40}\s.{40}$

Given received post content is:
"""
{
  "object_kind": "tag_push",
  "before": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "after": "82b3d5ae55f7080f1e6022629cdb57bfae7cccc7",
  "ref": "refs/tags/v1.0.0",
  "repository":{
    "git_ssh_url":"git@example.com:jsmith/example.git",
  }
}
"""
Then the job is triggered
Then variables are resolved to:
  | variable         | value                                    |
  | object_kind      | tag_push                                 |
  | before           | 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
  | after            | 82b3d5ae55f7080f1e6022629cdb57bfae7cccc7 |
  | ref              | refs/tags/v1.0.0                         |
  | git_ssh_url      | git@example.com:jsmith/example.git       |
```