# Jenkins Build from git tag

Tags: git, jenkins

I need advice from everyone, is it possible to create a jenkins job which prepares build from git tag (not from branch).

As I understood from one of my friend that it is not advised to create a jenkins job pointing to tag and one should always have job pointing to branch.

Context: I created tag on each release, now i want my Jenkins job, should be ready to provide build of each tag

Comment: Yes it is possible. a tag is just a pointer on the graph in the exact same way that a branch. The difference is you can't (easily) move tags. There's no reason not to build from a tag though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Git Plugin: How to build specific tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195900/jenkins-git-plugin-how-to-build-specific-tag)

Comment: Thanks , any suggestion on  tag vs branch

Comment: It's entirely dependant on what you want to do. Like I've already said; a tag is just a branch that doesn't move.