# What does the '^{}' at the end of a git tag mean?

Tags: git

when running this [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734181/how-to-get-list-of-latest-tags-in-remote-git) to obtain all available versions from origin...

`git ls-remote --tags | grep -i 'refs/tags/dev-[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*' | sort -r | head | grep -i '[^\/]*$'`

I get a list of unusual tags with unexpected endings:

```
From ****
*******93c7d****************        refs/tags/v0.0.11
*******bc823****************        refs/tags/v0.0.12
*******dcde9****************        refs/tags/V0.0.0
*******64632****************        refs/tags/V0.0.1^{}
*******1c2a1****************        refs/tags/v0.0.8^{}
*******6983d****************        refs/tags/v0.0.5
*******b7070****************        refs/tags/v0.0.6^{}
*******b11b1****************        refs/tags/v0.0.3
*******53965****************        refs/tags/v0.0.7^{}
*******42cf3****************        refs/tags/v0.0.12^{}
```

(censored for security reasons)

**`man git-tag`** and **`man git-ls-remote`** don't tell me anything.

Can someone tell me what the ^{} at the end means?

Comment: I don't know about your particular case, but curly bracers after a reference is usually meant to point to a revision. Check [gitrevisions](http://schacon.github.io/git/gitrevisions.html).

Comment: by the answer i provided, does this imply that the tag points to another tag?

Comment: I don't think so. It sounds like having an empty curly braces is roughly equivalent to having no reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the [reference](http://schacon.github.io/git/gitrevisions.html) given from @amenadiel

This is an excerpt from the website that explains what it is

> `<rev>^{}, e.g. v0.99.8^{}`
>
> A suffix ^ followed by an empty brace pair means the object could be a tag, and dereference the tag recursively until a non-tag object is found.

Comment: What does it mean in plain English?