# Get all git repository release tags using grunt or node

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, gruntjs, build-process

I need to get all release tags from remote git repository.
Anyone have any ideas how could I do it using grunt or node?

Comment: List all tags in a local repo? Fetch all tags from a remote repo? What page?

Comment: @Trott Remote repo. What page it doesn't matter actually.. I just need to get tags list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need clarify your question a bit, since it a bit unclear, is repository is local or remote, for example. This makes difference.

But I believe I can describe approach to you, so you can decide what to do (or what to ask next);

If you have local repository, you have folder there called `.git` in contains all information about source code. In most cases this information is in plain text and could be easily accessed via standard `node` tools.

For example, look on the contents of the following folder: `.git/refs`:
* You will find all local branches as a files in subfolder `.git/refs/heads`;
* All remote branches current repository aware of are in `.git/refs/remotes/origin` (more remote end-points you have, more you will find subfolders in that folder);
* Tags are in `.git/refs/tags`;

Read listing of the folder and you will get the names of needed tags.

Comment: It is remote repository. I have only repository url, and i should get tags list from this repository.

Comment: You can always call `git` executable as it was described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734181/how-to-get-list-of-latest-tags-in-remote-git

Comment: If repository you're working with is in GitHub, you can try to get tags by asking awesome REST API provided by GitHub: https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/

Comment: yes, but how can I call this using grunt. I need to automate  this process.