# Git parameter plugin to get Tags from branches

Tags: git, jenkins

I am using git parameter plugin for tag and in branch section i have specified particular branch. Then it should show all tags which are created to that branch only but it is showing all the tags from all the different branches.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I need to filter tags for a branch. Suppose I have "Lab2_Release" branch then only want to get tags for this branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering there is no refspec you could put in the Jenkins Git plugin ([as tried here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747145/6309)), you could go with a [Extensible Choice plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin), and a groovy script [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18112484/6309).

In your case, the groovy script would start listing tags for a branch with [`git tag --merged <branch>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084124/6309).